# How to solve 4 equations with 3 variables in Stokes parameters calculation

Tags: equation-solving

I am studying the [Stokes parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_parameters) and  I need to solve the following 4 equations (for S0, S1, S2 and S3) with 3 variables:

```
NSolve[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x^2 - y^2 == 0.28, 2 x y Cos[z] == 0.831384, 2 x y Sin[z] == 0.48}, {x, y, z}], where x, y and z are complex numbers.
```

The Mathematica has no output. I am afraid the command NSolve is not properly used. My question is how to solve this problem. Any help or prompt is highly appreciated.

P.S.

If we check the first three equations

```
 NSolve[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x^2 - y^2 == 0.28, 2 x y Cos[z] == 0.831384}, {x, y, z}]
```

or the last three equations

```
  NSolve[{x^2 - y^2 == 0.28, 2 x y Cos[z] == 0.831384, 2 x y Sin[z] == 0.48}, {x, y, z}]
```

we can obtain a common solution of {x = 0.8; y = 0.6; z = 0.5236;}.
This means  {x = 0.8; y = 0.6; z = 0.5236;} is just the right solution.

Or, if we try

```
  Solve[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x^2 - y^2 == 7/25,   2 x y Cos[z] == (12 Sqrt[3])/25, 2 x y Sin[z] == 12/25}, {x, y, z},   Modulus -> Automatic]
```

we can obtain the solution of  {x = 0.8; y = 0.6; z = Pi/6;}. However, it is difficult to obtain value of (12 Sqrt[3])/25 in experiment.

Comment: `NMinimize[{(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2,x^2+y^2==1,x^2-y^2==0.28,2 x y Cos[z]==0.831384,2 x y Sin[z]==0.48},{x,y,z}]`

Comment: Many thanks to @chyanog ! This method really works. But it is difficult to understand the principle of this method. x,y,z  can always satisfy the four equations and simultaneously minimize (x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2?